# Create database for treeview in android

Tags: sqlite, realm

I want to create a database for treeview in android but level number  for any node (group)uncertain.how to create such a database? [Database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7jvM.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at this - http://charlesleifer.com/blog/querying-tree-structures-in-sqlite-using-python-and-the-transitive-closure-extension/

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is not large. Just save it as string (for instance, using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) then parse saved string to object again for later use

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create a database for a treeview.
I guess you want to know how to structure the actual table for the tree?
Then have a look here: [tree structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)

This gives an overview of the most used strategies. Most used is the 'parent reference' strategy.

Comment: i want create Similar to this database http://s8.picofile.com/file/8348486092/photo_2019_01_10_13_15_41.jpg

Comment: and according to your tags of the question, i guess you want to use sqlite?

Comment: the link provided, gives you an example on how to do it. if you have any problems understanding the article, let me know whats so difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance